# Is there a high-performance tracing library for linux?

Tags: linux, framework, logs

(moved [from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55915260/6610)) In the past, I encountered Event Tracing for Windows, a tracing system designed to store as little as possible, as fast as possible.

Basically, this system allows you to log message *IDs*.  This makes sense: after all, you don't need to store the full message string if it's always going to be the same.  (you could append context arguments to it, too).  It's up to the log viewer to 'decode' the logs, based on an ID->format mapping.

Is there a counterpart for this on Linux?